# C++ - Extract template parameter from derived class

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

Can I extract the type parameter from the derived class? Something like this:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
...
};

struct TheType {};

class B : public A<TheType> {
...
};

template<typename DerivedClass>
class C {
  // If DerivedClass is B
  // Can I extract the type parameter T of B:A<T> inside of C?
  DerivedClass elem;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `type` in `A`:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
protected:
    using type = T;
    ...
};
```

Then you can use `typename DerivedClass::type` in `C`.

Comment: It's `using type = T;`.

Answer (score 2):

Without modifying `A`, you might do:

```
// declaration only
template <typename T> T ATemplateTypeImpl(const A<T>&);

template <typename T>
using ATemplateType = decltype(ATemplateTypeImpl(std::declval<T>()));


static_assert(std::is_same<TheType, ATemplateType<B>>);
```

Comment: *Without modifying A* :) Very nice.